# An algorithm to efficiently insert a list of elements into a binary heap ("bulk insertion")

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

I wonder if there is any elegant algorithm for inserting a list of elements into a binary heap (at once) whose performance would be close to that of inserting elements one by one when there are only a few elements to insert, and which would still run in linear time in the worst case (when there is a lot of elements to insert).

Comment: Assume *n* to be the number of new elements, *m* the size of the heap "before". Brute force: fix a limit below which to insert one by one ($O(\log m)$ with a self-respecting heap implementation), build afresh above ($O(m+n)$). With a fast merge for heaps (*not* given for *binary heap*s as per English wikipedia), there may be a region where turning the new elements into a heap ($O(n)$) and merging beats rebuilding. Elegance lies in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @greybeard, in my eye this is not elegant.  I wonder for what proportion of the Earth's population it is.

Comment: (I wonder what the *this* in `in my eye this is not elegant` is referring to.)

Comment: @greybeard: your "brute force" solution.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) describes a procedure, due to Floyd, which constructs a heap from an array in linear time.

It also mentions a [procedure](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00264229) for merging two heaps, of sizes $n$ and $k$, in time $O(k + \log k \log n)$.

Altogether, we can add $k$ elements to a heap of length $n$ in time $O(k + \log k \log n)$: first build a heap containing $k$ elements to be inserted (takes $O(k)$ time), then merge that with the heap of size $n$ (takes $O(k+ \log k \log n)$ time).

Compare this to repeated insertion, which would run in time $O(k\log n)$.

Comment: My question is about inserting elements into an existing heap. It can happen that there is only 10 elements to insert into a heap of  10000 elements. "[...] whose performance would be close to that of inserting elements one by one when there are only a few elements to insert [...]"

Comment: Wikipedia mentions an algorithm for merging two heaps, of sizes $n$ and $k$, in time $O(\log n \log k)$. See [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00264229). Does this help you?

Answer (score 3):

A citation without too much consideration or research:
[heap bulk insert, Elmasry/Katajainen style](http://www.cphstl.dk/Report/Binary-heaps/cphstl-report-2013-1.pdf) (figure 3):

**procedure:** *bulk-insert*
**input:** $A[1..n_0+l]$: array; $n_0$: index; $l$:  index
**data structures:** $A[1..n_0]$: partial heap; $A[n_0+ 1..n_0+l]$: buffer
$right$ ← $n_0+l$
$left$ ← $\max \{n_0+ 1, \lfloor (n_0 + l)/2 \rfloor\}$
**while** $right \ne 1$
   $left ← \lfloor left/2 \rfloor$
   $right ← \lfloor right/2 \rfloor$
   **for** $j \in \{right, right−1, \cdots, left\}$
      *sift-down*$(A, j, n_0+l$)

Elmasry, Amr; Katajainen, Jyrki: *Towards ultimate binary heaps*

Comment: Looks a straightforward adaption of (the better part of) Floyd's *Treesort 3* (ACM Algorithm 245); as such, there may be prior art. Elegant in the eye of an old hand at coding.